# How to set other repo as a part of my project when git add?

Tags: git, github

I clone one remote repo `A` into local, and set it as one part of my project. However, when I want to push the whole project (include the repo `A`) into remote server, I find that the `A` is not actually included. How to fix it?

By the way, the `A` of my project in remote server seems just a link, without any files.

Comment: plz try this way https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging

Answer (score 1):

Use GitHub submodule, read at here: https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules

Answer (score 0):

Use [git subtree](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/) to connect `A` to your project.
`git subtree` will merge `A`'s commit history to your project's history, and you will be able to modify and commit files in `A` without affecting original `A`.

If you don't need to modify `A`, `git submodule` is another option. It just add kinda reference to `A` to your project.